# Will AngularJS/Javascript "crash" after a long browser (even on mobile) timeout?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, browser, timeout

I'm developing a web app using AngularJS.
It will run for both desktop and mobile browsers and my question is:

**Will AngularJS/JavaScript have any problem after long timeouts or due to Android memory management? Will they ever "crash" or be shut down?**

So if I browse my page, minimize the browser and get back to it after some hours, will the environment still be ok or do I have to reload everything to make it work?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by timeouts. The browser will keep running all its tabs until the computer goes to sleep. During sleep, applications freeze and your Javascript will not run. But of course, if you have Javascript that keeps accumulating memory indefinitely while the computer is awake, then yes, the tab will eventually crash.

Comment: With timeout I mean long time of unusage, specially on smartphones. I fear that memory management is to wipe out apps that aren't used for long time and that this might mean that the environment will eventually break.

Comment: Mobile apps are suspended in the background (that includes browser apps and their tabs and subsequently, the Javascript). Usually when coming back to the browser app, the browser will refresh the page to update the content on it. Websites should not break on page refreshes...

Comment: No way to answer this without knowing what you do inside the app